# What is anti-representation?

Tags: representation-theory

Definition:  ($\Gamma$ is (semi)group) A right $K \Gamma$-module can be regarded as a pair $(V, \tau)$ where $\tau: \Gamma \rightarrow \operatorname{End}_{K}(V)$ is an anti-representation of $\Gamma$ on the $K$-space $V$, i.e. $\tau\left(g g^{\prime}\right)=\tau\left(g^{\prime}\right) \tau(g)$ for all $g, g^{\prime} \in \Gamma, \tau\left(1_{\Gamma}\right)=\mathbb{I}_{V}$.

I can see how the right $K \Gamma$-module can be made into anti-representation and vice versa. But I don't understand what anti-representation is concretely(or even abstractly). I tried working with $S_{3}$ and its standard representation but could only conclude that it is not a representation.

Comment: "Anti-representation" just means a representation that switches the order of multiplication, which is exactly the definition you gave: $\tau(g g') = \tau(g') \tau(g)$.

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan Does it occur anywhere naturally? I had dealt with the right actions and right modules but all I can see is an abstract connection to anti-representation by defining $v \bullet g = \tau(g)v$ .

Comment: Well, they come from right actions, and those occur naturally in many places. A general pattern is that if $G$ admits a left action on a set $X$ then that gives rise to a right action on the set of functions $X \to Y$, and various specializations of this.

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan Just to clarify here, does a set of functions $X \rightarrow Y$ have an additional structure, like that of vector space in this particular context? When I consider vector space, and its dual things work out nicely(I think of this as prototypical example of this). That is $\tau : G \rightarrow GL(V)$, $g \mapsto \tau(g)(\in GL(V) \mapsto gv$ gives representation and $\pi : G \rightarrow GL(V^{*})$ gives anti-representation. But I still don't understand why and how?

Comment: It can but it doesn't have to. The general pattern is that precomposition $f(x) \mapsto f(gx)$ switches the order of composition, which is a very simple computation: if we precompose with $h$ and then with $g$ we get $f(hx)$ and then $f(hgx)$.

Comment: A *representation* of $\Gamma$ on the vector space $V$ is a monoid homomorphism $\rho \colon \Gamma \to \operatorname{GL}(V)$, i.e. a map of monoids such that $\rho(1) = \operatorname{id}_V$ and $\rho(ab) = \rho(a) \rho(b)$. An *anti-representation* $\tau$ is a monoid anti-homomorphism: the order of multiplication reverses: $\tau(ab) = \tau(b) \tau(a)$. Anti-homomorphisms (of monoids, groups, rings, etc) are almost as good as homomorphisms, the have similar isomorphism theorems and so on. The composition of two anti-homs is a hom, while an anti-hom composed with a hom is again an anti-hom.